# PHP xampp downloading my index.php instead of loading the page

Tags: php, xampp

So my PHP project is causing `localhost` as well as `localhost/project/` is downloading the `index.php` for the project rather than loading it, it downloads it as `download`...here is the `download` file:

```
<?php   
/*
* Index.php - Define the directories
*
*
* DS, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR = /
* ROOT, dirname = string containing the path of a file or directory
* __FILE__ = The full path and filename of the file. If used inside an include, the name of the included file is returned
*
* In this file we load the apporpriate files that our website wants to load and render the
* template with informatio from the database. We load the bootstrap.php from the library folder.
*
* We are not including the ?\>  to avoid injection of any extra whitespaces in our output.
*
*
*/


define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('ROOT', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));

$url = $_GET['url'];

require_once (ROOT . DS . 'library' . DS . 'bootstrap.php');
```

And loading `localhost` downloads this:

```
<?php
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && ('on' == $_SERVER['HTTPS'])) {
        $uri = 'https://';
    } else {
        $uri = 'http://';
    }
    $uri .= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    header('Location: '.$uri.'/xampp/');
    exit;
?>
Something is wrong with the XAMPP installation :-(
```

Comment: You might not have loaded the PHP module for apache?

Comment: Do you know how to load this manually on ubuntu? I will search to try it

Comment: Are you actually using XAMPP on Ubuntu? I mean, the stuff from apachefriends? - they can't even get their own website right (Or is #META TITLE# supposed to be the actual page title?). Just "sudo apt-get install apache2 php5 libapache2-mod-php5 mysql" and off you go...

Comment: Hey @germainelol, did you actually get to find the solution for this. I think I got the exact same problem....

Comment: I don't think this is an issue with php handler. Check whether your index.php file is having executive permission. Try "chmod 644 index.php". Give 644 permission for index.php. It will resolve :)

Answer (score 5):

I have the same problem (using Ubuntu 12.04) and also have a line in the .htaccess like pi4r0n, e.g.,

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54s .php
```

The XAMPP does not have the same version of PHP as the `AddHandler`command is calling (mine has v5.3.8). I have found that commenting it out, as pi4r0n did, i.e.,

```
# AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54s .php
```

will allow it to work on the local server. You just need to remember to change it before uploading it.

Comment: Thanks it worked in my mac.
I struggled to find the reason to make it work and followed all the available answers.
Finally just commenting the above mentioned in .htaccess file it worked.

Comment: This helped me as well! Technically original credit to @pi4r0n but this was closer to my exact answer. Thank you both!

Answer (score 1):

Guys I had exactly the same problem as well and in my cases it was htaccess file. By mistake I have download it from my server (cPanel server) and the htaccess looked like this

**# Use PHP5.4 as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php**

but because I do not have PHP5.4 installed it locally on XAMPP, it did not know what to do with the file.

So my advice would be to make sure your **htaccess** files if you got any are removed or are correct ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on my Ubuntu desktop computer. Using filezilla (or any other file explorer) I deleted a hidden a htaccess file from the parent directory.

And it was solved. Back to normal web page display.

(I am not sure if that htaccess file was important for the desktop computer, but I am sure I did not add that on my live server..hence I deleted it. Let me know if I am wrong)

Answer (score 0):

This is for MAC Version 10.15.4.

If you have XAMPP installed, you can try adding following lines to httpd.conf locating at /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/conf.

AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm .html

If I do not work, try to delete cache of your browsers or restart your computer.

Note: If you have .htaccess file in the same root directory, you should delete it to prevent browsers download your php or html file.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to updating php.ini file and setting enable_post_data_reading=On, make sure you start XAMPP (go to where it's installed and doubleclick xampp_start)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem is that I have the project in cPanel and if try to execute the project in my local, Xampp upload file instead open localhost.

In cPanel I have the version 7.2 of php and in my local I have version 7.4.

In my case the reason of this uses is that cPanel generate a handler in the .htaccess file:

```
# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php72” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php74 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

so to be able to execute the project in local we need to comment this line, like this:

```
#AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php74 .php .php7 .phtml
```

Answer (score -1):

**

### this error comes up due to few codes written in .htaccess when you upload your file in Cpanel you just have to remove this part of the code in .htaccess file solve this download error
or change the version of php in .htaccess file.

### remove "#" sign as well

php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit Set the “ea-php74”

package as the default “PHP” programming language.

AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php74___lsphp .php .php7 .phtml

php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit

### **Or just use this .htacess file downloading from the link**

```html
https://mega.nz/file/PU803bDA#evpjZZ0Yz6KQYw8xWVvIz_RNqV4xeyHq5RhDEtcNUYI
```

Comment: Please include the file as plaintext.