# PHP file gets downloaded instead of executing

Tags: php, windows, xampp, github-pages

I have hosted my site on GitHub. It loads the first page. But when another page is clicked from that link, it gets downloaded. I am using PHP from XAMPP in Windows.

```
**<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="login.php">Login as Staff</a>
    
</body>
</html>**
```

This is the first page. It was supposed to go to the login.php page. But it gets downloaded.

Comment: github pages is not php hosting

Comment: ["GitHub Pages does not support server-side languages such as PHP, Ruby, or Python."](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/about-github-pages)

Comment: I didn't know that PHP is not supported on GitHub pages. Thank you!

Comment: If you want to upload PHP files then you can use 'Heroku' instead. Just Saying, if you use PHP on Heroku and face any problem during deploying your GitHub Repository then create a 'index.php' file(if you do not have), this might solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Similar is with solution can be found here [PHP xampp downloading my index.php instead of loading the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17631299/php-xampp-downloading-my-index-php-instead-of-loading-the-page)

You have to add a handler in your .htaccess file.

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54s .php
```

You'll have to update the php version to yours though. For example

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php73 .php
```

for PHP version 7.3

Comment: Where can I find the .htaccess file?

Comment: If one does not exist, you can simply create one in the root directory of your project.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem. It perplexed me for 4 days.

I used visual studio and live server. When I clicked live server, the address generated is http://localhost:5500/index.html. This address caused the php file being downloaded instead of executed. After changing it to http://127.0.0.1/gre/index.html, the php file that the index page links to is executed correctly.

In my case, index.html file is in htdocs/gre/index.html, so I must access it with http://127.0.0.1/gre/index.html

If your index page is in a folder in the htdocs, you must add the folder's name in the url.

I cannot believe this small thing costs me so long to figure out...